# Unable to load SWF in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am working in flash and as3. I am new to as3. I was trying to load and unload the SWF file.

My project contains 2 files, one is index file and the other is animal file. In the index page I have button for animal. When I click on this button the animal SWF starts executing. But the problem is when I click on index button of animal SWF, it is not showing index page again, instead it is showing message as

> Unable to load SWF

My index page code is:

> ```
> var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("animal/animal.swf");
> swfLoader.load(urlReq);
> swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, swfLoadComplete);
> swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,
>     swfLoadError);
> function swfLoadComplete(evt:Event):void
> {
> var loader:Loader = Loader(evt.target.loader);
> addChild(loader.content);
> swfLoader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, swfLoadComplete);
> }
> function swfLoadError(evt:IOErrorEvent):void
> { 
>   trace("Unable to load swf ");
>   swfLoader.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, swfLoadError);
>   }
> ```

So what to do to load the index SWF from animal SWF?

Comment: it is not like in AS2 where one swf could replace content of currenlty loaded SWF - your index.swf is your main SWF which loaded into itself animal.swf

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to add to the displaylist. Use `addChild`.

```
var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("animal/animal.swf");
swfLoader.load(urlReq);
this.addChild(swfLoader);
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html

Update: I see its not loaded. You have an `IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR`. Mostly this means the file is not located at that url. Check the location or use a http debugger to find out which location you are trying to open.

Comment: even after writing this.addChild(swfLoader);    it is showing the same error

Comment: I have checked the path. The file is located at the same location